# Displaying Tooltip from a disabled Textbox in a Winform Tabpage

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, tooltip

I have a disabled textbox having values placed in a tab page in a windows form. 
When i mouse hover the control , the tooltip is not displaying. the Mousemove event or any of the moue related events are not getting fired since it is disabled.

Help me in fixing this issue. 
Thanks in advance.
Note: Form's Mousemove and Tab's Mousemove events were tried but nothing worked out.

-Rejishankar

Comment: Is this TextBox ever enabled?  If not then use a Label instead of a TextBox.

Comment: When a control is disabled, all its internal code is disabled also. Instead of disabling it, you could set the `.ReadOnly` property to true. This way, the user can't edit it, but everything else works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this and it worked

Answer (score 0):

When a control is disabled, all its internal code is disabled also. Instead of disabling it, you could set the .**ReadOnly** property to **true**. This way, the user can't edit it, but everything else works

– David Wilson